# Comparison operators not supported for type System.Collections.Generic.List in a .Where lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm using a lambda expression and I'm getting an exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'

```
.Where(a => a.ID == paramId && MyPrettyFunction(a.ValueA).Contains(a.ValueB))
```

In this extract, `MyPrettyFunction` returns a static `List<int>`, and `a.ValueA` and `B` are `int`.

I appreciate any help! Thank you very much!

Comment: is this actually a LINQ-to-EF (or similar) database usage? it matters - some things can't be trivially translated to SQL etc

Comment: Hmm need to see more of the code to help on this one.

Comment: @mathis1337 What do you mean? The lambda is fine - the `Where` clause returns a `bool`, which is used to filter the results.

Comment: Your code as presented works fine on a simple `List<T>`. Please post a code sample that reproduces the issue, or include more details on the datasource.

Answer (score 1):

Can you pleas share the full code, because below code works fine for me

```
namespace TestProjects
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int ID;
        public int ValueA;
        public int ValueB;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Test> obj = new List<Test>
            {
                new Test{ID=1,ValueA=2,ValueB=3},
                new Test{ID=2,ValueA=2,ValueB=3},
                new Test{ID=3,ValueA=2,ValueB=3},
                new Test{ID=4,ValueA=2,ValueB=3},
            };
           var Test= obj.Where(a => a.ID == 3 && MyPrettyFunction(a.ValueA).Contains(a.ValueB)).ToList();
        }
        public static List<int> MyPrettyFunction(int i)
        {
            return new List<int>{ 1,2,3,5};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @RufusL a; that isn't possible for sundara yet (rep), and b: it wouldn't fit/format; personally: I'm OK with it here

Comment: @MarcGravell Ok, we can agree to disagree. I would argue that: a) not having rep to make a comment doesn't mean comments should be posted as answers, and b) the sample code isn't required to tell the OP that their question doesn't repro with the given information.

Comment: I'm glad to see the moderators exercise some flexibility in their judgement on these types of answers that don't fit the answer format, but nonetheless contribute value. In this case, having a fully functional code example may help the OP isolate why their code isn't working by evaluating the differences.